# VBScript regex to match all URLS not in an anchor

Tags: regex, asp-classic, vbscript, find

I'm pulling my hair out over this one, it seems you can't do a regex for `doesn't begin with` in VBScript.

I've started writing a difficult messy piece of code that finds them but I'd rather find a better simpler way.

The sample input is:

```
<a href="http://www.scirra.com/forum" target="_blank" title="Some value">my link text</a><br /><br />
<a href="http://www.scirra.com/blog" target="_blank" title="Some value">http://www.scirra.com/blog</a><br /><br />
<a href="http://www.scirra.com" target="_blank" title="Some value">http://www.scirra.com</a><br /><br />
<a href="http://www.scirra.com" target="_blank" title="A title">tester</a><br /><br />
http://www.google.com<br /><br />
http://www.scirra.com/blog<br /><br />
https://www.scirra.com
```

As you can see, the last 3 URLS are not wrapped in anchor tags and need to be.  I was trying to build a rule where it matches `https?://` where it doesn't start with an `<a>` tag but I can't figure out an easy way to do it.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately vbscript doesn't have lookbehinds (see [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refflavors.html) for a list of what flavours of regex have what features)

You could always match something like:

```
(^|[^>])(https?://[rest_of_url_regex_here])
```

And then if you're doing a find/replace, replace with `\1<a href="\2">\2</a>` to put back that extra character you captured.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is going to work well, if someone does `<b>http://www.google.com</b>` it wont match. :(

Comment: well the recommended way to parse HTML/XML is to use some sort of parser specially built for it, exactly because regex fails on that sort of problem. Regex is pretty bad for parsing HTML.